# Remapping the rear outputs of my sound device to the front outputs (remapping 4.1 to stereo)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a sound device which is technically 4.1, but I am only able to use two outputs from it (front left and front right). This works fine for stereo applications, but certain games that support surround sound audio try to play sounds in the rear channels, which results in audio I can't hear.

I would like to remap these rear channels to the front ones.

I think the right starting place is with a `pacmd` remap command. Currently, the one I have is this:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=rear_stereo master=alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-surround-40 channels=2 master_channel_map=rear-left,rear-right channel_map=front-left,front-right remix=no
```

However, this doesn't work (if I test the rear left or right outputs, they're still inaudible). What is the correct command to make this remap work?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the command I used was this:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=remap-41-full master=alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-surround-40 channels=4 master_channel_map=front-left,front-right,front-left,front-right channel_map=rear-left,rear-right,front-left,front-right remix=yes
```

Obviously you'll need to change `alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-surround-40` to the name of your actual audio sink (obtained from `pacmd list-sources | grep name:`). What I didn't realise is that `channel_map` is where the sound comes from, and `master_channel_map` is where it will end up. So you want to list the rear channels in the `channel_map`, and remap them into front channels in the `master_channel_map`.

This creates a new output device, and once you set pulseaudio to use it, will correctly remap rear audio to front audio.